# Change the template of a modal from within the modal in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I open a modal like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="showLogin()">Sign in</a>
```

Login Function

```
$scope.showLogin= function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
       templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
       controller: 'modalController',
   })
 };
```

ModalController (generic)

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller("modalController", function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

    $scope.cancel = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

});
```

Login.html

```
<form>
</form>
<a href="#" ng-click="showSignup()">Sign up</a>
```

When signup is clicked, I can open the sign up modal. Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mR3nXYo1rm4ey5Buc9Q0?p=preview

My question is, Is it possible to just swap the template? When Signup is clicked I want to change the template from register.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Just use

```
<div ng-if="model.modalType === 'login'">
  <form>
  </form>
  <a href="#" ng-click="model.modalType = 'signup'">Sign up</a>
</div>
<div ng-if="model.modalType === 'signup'">
  ...
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.model = {
  modalType: 'login'
};
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Is it posssible to do this without polluting modalinstanceCtrl? I want to keep it generic so it can be used by other modals as well.

Comment: Nest the whole thing inside a `<div ng-controller="LoginAndSignupCtrl">`, for example.